# How to make equation array look more neat and compact

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I'm writing a document that has a long list of two equation arrays. As it stands, the arrays seem very tedious and clustered, and I'm unsure of what'd be the best way to make it look more neat without having to break them in parts.

Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{calc} 

            \begin{document}
            \begin{eqnarray*}
    & & \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} \cdot (v - b - \epsilon (b - \rho )) - G(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) = 0. \\
    & \Longrightarrow & \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) - G(v)(1 + \epsilon ) = 0, \\
    & \Longrightarrow & \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) = G(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\ 
    & \Longrightarrow & g(v) (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) = G(v) \cdot \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\ 
    & \Longrightarrow & g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v) - g(v) \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho ) = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\
    & \Longrightarrow & g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \epsilon \rho = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ), \\
    & \Longrightarrow & g(v)v + g(v) \epsilon \rho = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\
    & \Longrightarrow &  [ G(v) \beta^{'}(v) + g(v) \beta(v) ] (1 + \epsilon ) = g(v)\cdot v + g(v) \epsilon \rho, \\
    & \Longrightarrow & \frac{d}{dv}[G(v) \beta(v)] = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Big [ g(v) v + g(v) \epsilon \rho \Big ], \\
    & \Longrightarrow & \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{d}{dw}[G(w) \beta(w)] = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Big [ g(w)w + g(w)\cdot \epsilon \rho \Big ], \\
    & \Longrightarrow & G(v) \beta(v) = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Big [ g(w) (w + \epsilon \cdot \rho ) \Big ], \\
    \end{eqnarray*}

     Integrating by parts, we have:

    \begin{eqnarray*}
    \beta(v) & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg [ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)\epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\ 
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg [ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{G(w)w}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} -   \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} + \epsilon \rho \Bigg ( \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg ) \Bigg ], \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \Bigg ( G(w)w \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} + \epsilon \rho G(w) \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg ) - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \Bigg ( G(v)v - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r))} \bar{v}(r) + \epsilon \rho (G(v) - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r)})  \Bigg ) - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{\cancel{G(v)}} \Bigg ( \cancel{G(v)}v + \epsilon \rho \cancel{G(v)}  \Bigg ) - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ] \\
    & = & \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ v + \epsilon \rho  - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
\end{eqnarray*}
            \end{document}
```

firs part of equations you can see below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to run the code and display my output over here. If someone can let me know, I'll do that and edit the questions. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) you cannot run code here, (3) please prepare a full minimal example, which we can just copy and test, here the preamble etc is missing. It might seem odd to you, but it makes helping other a lot easier for us (4) please do not use `eqnarray` it is very flawed and has inconsistent typography. Use `amsmath` and `align` instead (also saves a `&`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just a first comment: one shouldn't use eqnaray any more. It produces bad spacings, and should be replaced with one of the `ams` environments (`align` and the like).

Comment: I edited the code with you can copy and paste. 

Using the align environment simply ruined it more for me; maybe I don't know how to effectively use it since I have been using the eqnarray environment. 

Please let me know how I can best improve the output.

Comment: Can you explain what is "more net" for you? your question is very opinion based ...

Comment: I just mean that the equations seem to more clustered around each because there are a lot of equations. With a few equations, that isn't a problem with eqnarray and I have been using that all along.

Anything that makes the output look more aesthetically written (neat, easy to read, not this cluttered etc.) to the general audience reading the equations.

Comment: mainly I would remove all the `\displaystyle` they are forcing the line spacing to be uneven and that is a large part of the reason why the display looks unbalanced.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could show fewer equations if you used words to explain the necessary steps. The steps as far as the first integration could be presented as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
We start from the fact that
\begin{equation*} 
 \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - b - \epsilon (b - \rho )) - G(v) (1 + \epsilon ) = 0. 
\end{equation*}
Since $b=\beta(v)$, a straightforward rearrangement shows that
\begin{equation*}
G(v) \beta'(v) + g(v) \beta(v) = g(v) \, \frac{v + \epsilon \rho}{1 + \epsilon}.
\end{equation*}
The left-hand side is now the derivative of a product, so that integrating yields
\begin{equation*} 
G(v)\beta(v) = \int g(v) \, \frac{v + \epsilon \rho}{1 + \epsilon} \, \mathrm{d} v     
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this looks any better, but here is a version using align*.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} \cdot (v - b - \epsilon (b - \rho )) - G(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) = 0. \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) - G(v)(1 + \epsilon ) = 0, \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) = G(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\ 
 &\Longrightarrow\quad g(v) (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) = G(v) \cdot \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\ 
 &\Longrightarrow\quad g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v) - g(v) \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho ) = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \epsilon \rho = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ), \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad g(v)v + g(v) \epsilon \rho = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad  [ G(v) \beta^{'}(v) + g(v) \beta(v) ] (1 + \epsilon ) = g(v)\cdot v + g(v) \epsilon \rho, \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{d}{dv}[G(v) \beta(v)] = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Big [ g(v) v + g(v) \epsilon \rho \Big ], \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{d}{dw}[G(w) \beta(w)] = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} 
  \Big [ g(w)w + g(w)\cdot \epsilon \rho \Big ], \\
 &\Longrightarrow\quad G(v) \beta(v) = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Big [ g(w) (w + \epsilon \cdot \rho ) \Big ],
\end{align*}

By integrating by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\beta(v) &= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg [ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)\epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\ 
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg [ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{G(w)w}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} -   \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} + \epsilon \rho \Bigg ( \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg ) \Bigg ], \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \Bigg ( G(w)w \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} + \epsilon \rho G(w) \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigg ) - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \Bigg (G(v)v - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r))} \bar{v}(r) + \epsilon \rho (G(v) - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r)})  \Bigg ) \\
&\phantom{\quad = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}} - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ \frac{1}{\cancel{G(v)}} \Bigg ( \cancel{G(v)}v + \epsilon \rho \cancel{G(v)}  \Bigg ) - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ] \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigg [ v + \epsilon \rho  - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg ], 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation on John Kormylo's solution using the AMS `align*` environment. The `align*` environment organises alignment in "pairs" so I have separated the `\Longrightarrow` from the equations with a `&&` and then there is a second alignment around the equals signs. For the first set of equations this produces (the second set I imagine is much the same as John's):

[image]

I have also replaced your `\Bigg ....\Bigg`'s with the more correct `\Biggl ... \Biggr`s and down-graded your `\Bigg(...\Bigg)` in the second equations to `\bigg(...\bigg)` as I think this looks better.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &&\frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} \cdot (v - b - \epsilon (b - \rho )) - G(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) &= 0. \\
    \Longrightarrow && \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) - G(v)(1 + \epsilon ) &= 0, \\
    \Longrightarrow && \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) &= G(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\
    \Longrightarrow && g(v) (v - \beta(v) - \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho )) &= G(v) \cdot \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\
    \Longrightarrow && g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v) - g(v) \epsilon (\beta(v) - \rho ) &= G(v) \beta^{'}(v) (1 + \epsilon ), \\
    \Longrightarrow && g(v) v - g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \epsilon \rho &= G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ), \\
    \Longrightarrow && g(v)v + g(v) \epsilon \rho &= G(v) \beta^{'}(v) \cdot (1 + \epsilon ) + g(v) \beta(v)(1 + \epsilon ), \\
    \Longrightarrow &&  [ G(v) \beta^{'}(v) + g(v) \beta(v) ] (1 + \epsilon ) &= g(v)\cdot v + g(v) \epsilon \rho, \\
    \Longrightarrow && \frac{d}{dv}[G(v) \beta(v)] &= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Bigl[ g(v) v + g(v) \epsilon \rho \Bigr], \\
    \Longrightarrow && \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{d}{dw}[G(w) \beta(w)] &= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigl[ g(w)w + g(w)\cdot \epsilon \rho \Bigr], \\
    \Longrightarrow && G(v) \beta(v) &= \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Bigl[ g(w) (w + \epsilon \cdot \rho ) \Bigr], \\
\end{align*}

     Integrating by parts, we have:

\begin{align*}
    \beta(v) & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Biggl[ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)\epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Biggl[ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) \epsilon \rho}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ \frac{G(w)w}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} -   \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} + \epsilon \rho \biggl( \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggr)\Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ \frac{1}{G(v)} \biggl( G(w)w \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} + \epsilon \rho G(w) \Bigg |_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggr)- \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ \frac{1}{G(v)} \biggl( G(v)v - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r))} \bar{v}(r) + \epsilon \rho (G(v) - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r)})  \biggr)- \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ \frac{1}{\cancel{G(v)}} \biggl( \cancel{G(v)}v + \epsilon \rho \cancel{G(v)}  \biggr)- \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Biggr] \\
    & = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon} \Biggl[ v + \epsilon \rho  - \int_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \Biggr], \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use `array` for the first series, and `align*` for the second. I change the size of the delimiters: most of them were too large, at least for my taste:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, cancel, array, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} \begin{array}{c@{\implies{}} > {\displaystyle}l}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{ \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} · (v - b - ϵ(b - ρ)) - G(v) · (1 + ϵ) = 0. } \\
  \makebox[2em]{} & \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - β(v) - ϵ(β(v) - ρ)) - G(v)(1 + ϵ) = 0, \\
  & \frac{ \displaystyle g(v)}{\displaystyle \beta^{'}(v)} (v - β(v) - ϵ(β(v) - ρ)) = G(v)(1 + ϵ), \\
  & g(v) (v - β(v) - ϵ(β(v) - ρ)) = G(v) · \beta^{'}(v) (1 + ϵ), \\
  & g(v) v - g(v) β(v) - g(v) ϵ(β(v) - ρ) = G(v) \beta^{'}(v) (1 + ϵ), \\
  & g(v) v - g(v) β(v)(1 + ϵ) + g(v) ϵρ= G(v) \beta^{'}(v) · (1 + ϵ), \\
  & g(v)v + g(v) ϵρ= G(v) \beta^{'}(v) · (1 + ϵ) + g(v) β(v)(1 + ϵ), \\
  & [ G(v) \beta^{'}(v) + g(v) β(v) ] (1 + ϵ) = g(v) · v + g(v) ϵ\rho, \\[0.5ex]
    & \frac{d}{dv}[G(v) β(v)] = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \Big [ g(v) v + g(v) ϵρ\Big ], \\[2ex]
      & ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{d}{dw}[G(w) β(w)] = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Big [ g(w)w + g(w) · ϵρ\Big ], \\[2ex]
        & G(v) β(v) = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \Big [ g(w) (w + ϵ · ρ) \Big ],
        \end{array} \]
        Integrating by parts, we have
        \begin{align*}
          β(v) & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggl[ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) ϵρ}{G(v)} \biggr]
          = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl[ ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{g(w)ϵρ}{G(v)} \biggr ], \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggl [ \frac{g(w)w}{G(v)} + \frac{g(w) ϵρ}{G(v)} \biggr], \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl[ \frac{G(w)w}{G(v)} \biggr\rvert_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} - ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} + ϵρ\biggr( \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \biggr\rvert_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggr ) \biggr ], \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \biggl ( G(w)w \biggr \rvert_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} + ϵρG(w) \biggr \rvert_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \biggr ) - ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \biggr ], \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl [ \frac{1}{G(v)} \Bigl ( G(v)v - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r))} \bar{v}(r) + ϵρ(G(v) - \cancel{G(\bar{v}(r)}) \Bigr ) - ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \biggr ], \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl [ \frac{1}{\cancel{G(v)}} \Bigl ( \cancel{G(v)}v + ϵρ\cancel{G(v)} \Bigr ) - ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \biggr ] \\
                   & = \frac{1}{1 + ϵ} \biggl [ v + ϵρ- ∫_{\bar{v}(r)}^{v} \frac{G(w)}{G(v)} \biggr ], \\
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]